# When I use --clear-static-content and after deploy static content doesn't load any more

Tags: magento2, static-content

I'm using magento 2 and everytime I try to enable a module with --clear-static-content , after I upgrade , clean and deploy , but my static content doesn't load anymore. And when I do deploy , only the en_US content gets done , but not en_GB , and I am using en_GB. Any idea what it might cause this ?

Answer (score 1):

If you use production mode you need redeploy static content with command:

`bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: I do so , If I use only that , only my en_US content gets deployed ,   and if I do php bin/magento --ansi setup:static-content:deploy en_GB  , I get some of the content generated , but not the js files..

Comment: looks like bug, can you post it on github?

Comment: here it is https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4833

Comment: just managed to get it work , I had a conflict , by the way main function to get the content back in my case is     ` php bin/magento --ansi setup:static-content:deploy en_GB `